# Replace value from other dataframe

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I have a data frame (x) with a factor variable which has values seperated by comma. I have another data frame (y) with description for the same values. Now I want to replace the values in  the data frame (x) with the description from the data frame (y). Any help would be highly appreciated.

say for example, the two data frame looks like below

```
data frame (x)
    s.no    x
    1       2,5,45
    2       35,5
    3       45

data fram (y)
s.no    x   description
1       2      a
2       5      b
3       45     c
4       35     d
```

I need the output as below

```
s.no    x
1      a,b,c
2      d,b
c       c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `split` the 'x' column in 'x' dataset by ',', loop over the `list`, match the value with the 'x' column in 'y' to get the numeric index, get the corresponding 'description' value from 'y' and `paste` it together.

```
x$x <- sapply(strsplit(x$x, ","), function(z) 
           toString(y$description[match(as.numeric(z), y$x)]))

x
#  s.no       x
#1    1 a, b, c
#2    2    d, b
#3    3       c
```

NOTE: If the 'x' column in 'x' is `factor` class, use `strsplit(as.character(x$x, ","))`

Comment: sorry, didn't see you there. Deleted mine as it is very similar. Nobody ever sees you...You are like a ninja :)

Comment: @Sotos No problem.  You can come up with another idea with `mgsub` or something like that

Comment: @akrun since the variable is factor, i added as.character which throws an error saying "split is missing with no default". But if i convert the factor to character before applying the function, it works good and i got my update. correct me if i am wrong. Thanks you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

With `splitstackshape`:

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(x, 'x', ',', 'long')[setDT(y), on='x'][,.(x=paste(description, collapse=',')), s.no]

#   s.no     x
#1:    1 a,b,c
#2:    2   b,d
#3:    3     c
```

Comment: When using the `splitstackshape`-package, using `setDT` is not necessarily.

Answer (score 4):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
  separate(x, paste0('x',1:3),',',convert=TRUE) %>% 
  gather(var, x, -1, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  left_join(., y, by='x') %>% 
  group_by(s.no = s.no.x) %>% 
  summarise(x = paste(description,collapse = ','))
```

the result:

```
   s.no     x
  (int) (chr)
1     1 a,b,c
2     2   d,b
3     3     c
```

Comment: do you realize what you posted is just a copy paste of my solution?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Didn't see it untill after I posted. I removed the `cSplit` solution.

Comment: nice solution with dplyr, +1